# Python pandas calculate time until value in a column is greater than it is in current period

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, time

I have a pandas dataframe in python with several columns and a datetime stamp. I want to create a new column, that calculates the time until output is less than what it is in the current period.

My current table looks something like this:

```
 datetime               output
 2014-05-01 01:00:00    3
 2014-05-01 01:00:01    2
 2014-05-01 01:00:02    3
 2014-05-01 01:00:03    2
 2014-05-01 01:00:04    1
```

I'm trying to get my table to have an extra column and look like this:

```
 datetime               output     secondsuntildecrease
 2014-05-01 01:00:00    3         1
 2014-05-01 01:00:01    2         3
 2014-05-01 01:00:02    3         1
 2014-05-01 01:00:03    2         1
 2014-05-01 01:00:04    1
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you compute the value of the 3rd column? Is that the purpose of the question? Or you just want to add a column to an existing csv file?

Answer (score 3):

```
upper_triangle     = np.triu(df.output.values < df.output.values[:, None])
df['datetime']     = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
df['s_until_dec']  = df['datetime'][upper_triangle.argmax(axis=1)].values - df['datetime']
df.loc[~upper_triangle.any(axis=1), 's_until_dec'] = np.nan
df
             datetime  output           s_until_dec
0 2014-05-01 01:00:00       3              00:00:01
1 2014-05-01 01:00:01       2              00:00:03
2 2014-05-01 01:00:02       3              00:00:01
3 2014-05-01 01:00:03       2              00:00:01
4 2014-05-01 01:00:04       1                   NaT
```

Here's how it works:

`df.output.values < df.output.values[:, None]` this creates a pairwise comparison matrix with broadcasting (`[:, None]` creates a new axis):

```
df.output.values < df.output.values[:, None]
Out: 
array([[False,  True, False,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Here, for example, `output[0]` is smaller than `output[1]` so the matrix element for (0, 1) is True. We need the upper triangle so I used `np.triu` to get the upper triangle of this matrix. `argmax()` will give me the index of the first `True` value. If I pass this into iloc, I will get the corresponding date. Except for the last one of course. It has all `False`s so I need to replace it with `np.nan`. `.loc` part checks that matrix for that case and replaces with `np.nan`.

Answer (score 2):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([3, 2, 3, 2, 1], index=pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2014-05-01 01:00:00', periods=5, freq='S'), columns=['output'])

def f(s):
    s = s[s & (s.index > s.name)]
    if s.empty:
        return np.nan
    else:
        return (s.index[0] - s.name).total_seconds()

df['secondsuntildecrease'] = df['output'].apply(lambda x: df['output'] < x).apply(f, axis=1)

df
```

outputs

```
                     output  secondsuntildecrease
2014-05-01 01:00:00       3                   1.0
2014-05-01 01:00:01       2                   3.0
2014-05-01 01:00:02       3                   1.0
2014-05-01 01:00:03       2                   1.0
2014-05-01 01:00:04       1                   NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one liner

```
df['seconds_until'] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(df.loc[(df['output'] < x['output']) & (df['datetime'] > x['datetime']), 'datetime'].min()) - pd.to_datetime(x[
'datetime']), axis=1)
```

output

```
              datetime  output  seconds_until
0  2014/05/01 01:00:00       3       00:00:01
1  2014/05/01 01:00:01       2       00:00:03
2  2014/05/01 01:00:02       3       00:00:01
3  2014/05/01 01:00:03       2       00:00:01
4  2014/05/01 01:00:04       1            NaT
```

Answer (score 1):

Use numpy's outer subtract to get matrix of differences.

Then filter using numpy's triangle function to ensure we only take differences for future times and stay out of the past.

Use numpy's where to make sure we don't get all False

Finally, take the difference in time.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(output=[3, 2, 3, 2, 1],
         datetime=pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2014-05-01 01:00:00', periods=5, freq='S'))
)

gt0 = np.triu(np.subtract.outer(df.output, df.output), 1) > 0
idx = np.where(gt0.any(1), gt0.argmax(1), np.nan)
-(df.datetime - df.loc[idx, 'datetime'].values).dt.total_seconds()

0    1.0
1    3.0
2    1.0
3    1.0
4    NaN
Name: datetime, dtype: float64
```

---

#### Timing

***Mine and ayhan's seem the most performant over small sample***

[image]

***ayhan's is best over 10,000 rows***

[image]